# mat-chip-grid is not being recognized in angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui, angular-material

I have the following and it is not working

```
    <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Enter fruits">
      <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let lang of languages"
                    (removed)="remove(lang)"
                    [editable]="true"
                    (edited)="edit(lang, $event)"
                    [aria-description]="'press enter to edit ' + lang.name">
        {{lang.name}}
        <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + lang.name">
          <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-chip-row>
      <input placeholder="New Lang..."
             [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
             [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
             (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
    </mat-chip-grid>
  </mat-form-field>

Component or directive matching mat-chip-row element is out of the current Angular module's scope
```

[image]

Here are my imports in my typescript chip class

[image]

Comment: Make sure you import the "new" module `import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';`, not the legacy one.

Comment: Did you import the dependencies in your app.module.ts?